# Integer value not getting refreshed

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to print even and odd using two separate threads which communicate with each other by wait and notify.

I do know that i refers to Integer object which is in heap. hence changes made by one thread should be visible to both thread. Also I am using volatile keyword for declaration of Integet i.

**I cant seem to understand how value of variable i is shown as 1 even after it has been incremented.**

The output of code is

```
 Even Thread got lock i=1
 Even Thread waiting.. i=1
 Odd Thread got lock i=1
Odd Thread  : i=2
 Odd Thread Run called NotifyAll
 Odd Thread got lock i=2
 Odd Thread waiting.. i=2
 Even Thread woken up.. i=1
 Even Thread waiting.. i=1
```

```
package programs;


public class EvenOdd {
    static Object lck = new Object();
    volatile static Integer i=1;
    volatile static Integer N = 1000;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        EvenRunner e = new EvenRunner(lck, i, N);
        OddRunner o = new OddRunner(lck, i, N);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(e,"Even Thread ");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(o,"Odd Thread ");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        }catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted : "+ex);
        }

    }
}
class EvenRunner implements Runnable{
    Object lck;
    Integer i;
    Integer N;
    EvenRunner(Object lck,Integer i,Integer N){
        this.lck=lck;
        this.i=i;
        this.N=N;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {


        while(i<N) {

            synchronized(lck) {
                System.out.println(" Even Thread got lock i="+i);
                while(i%2==1){
                    try {
                        System.out.println(" Even Thread waiting.. i="+i);
                        lck.wait();
                        System.out.println(" Even Thread woken up.. i="+i);
                    }catch(InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("Interrupted thread : "+e);
                    }
                }

                ++i;
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" : i="+i);

                System.out.println(" Even Thread Run called NotifyAll");
                lck.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
class OddRunner implements Runnable{
    Object lck;
    Integer i;
    Integer N;
    OddRunner(Object lck,Integer i,Integer N){
        this.lck=lck;
        this.i=i;
        this.N=N;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(i<N) {
            synchronized(lck) {
                System.out.println(" Odd Thread got lock i="+i);
                while(i%2==0){
                    try {
                        System.out.println(" Odd Thread waiting.. i="+i);
                        lck.wait();
                        System.out.println(" Odd Thread woken up.. i="+i);

                    }catch(InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("Interrupted thread : "+e);
                    }
                }

                ++i;
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" : i="+i);

                System.out.println(" Odd Thread Run called NotifyAll");
                lck.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected Result:** should be that other thread should also see the value of variable I as 2 after it has been incremented.

**Actual result:** value of variable i is read as 1 by other thread even after incrementing it.

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly advise you to follow Java naming conventions, with class names of `EvenRunner` and `OddRunner`.

Comment: Thanks sir, I would be more careful from next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Expected output should be that other thread should also see the value of variable I as 2 after it has been incremented.

When you construct `evenRunner` and `oddRunner`, you're copying the same `Integer` reference into each class as an instance field.

But `Integer` is immutable - when you execute `++i;` that changes the field to refer to a *different* `Integer` object. It doesn't modify the content of the *existing* integer object... so your two threads are operating on entirely separate fields, and won't interact at all.

If you want to have a *single* object that both threads can modify, use [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead.

Comment: Since Integer is immutable so there is no way of modifying it such that other thread reffering to it also sees the new value ? Right ?   I would need to create a mutable shared object if I want that functionality instead of a Integer object.

Comment: @ashish2199 yes, that's what 'immutable' means.

Comment: Also using an primitive would also not help because they would be local to each thread and other thread will not know what is the value of i in other thread and hence no syncing between the two. Right ?

Comment: @ashish2199: It's not that it would be local to the *thread* - it's that each *object* would have a separate field. You'd see the same behaviour here even if there was only one thread involved.